# C++ safety of using `new char[size]` for memory allocation and deallocation for arbitrary data

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have the following functions:

```
private:
    static char* new_data(std::size_t size) { return new char[size]; }
    template<typename T> static char* new_data(T& value) { return reinterpret_cast<char*>(new (new_data(sizeof(T))) T(value)); }
    template<typename T> static char* new_data(T&& value) { return reinterpret_cast<char*>(new (new_data(sizeof(T))) T(value)); }
    static void delete_data(char* data) { return delete[] data; }
```

(Note: `T` is any type, except it won't overload any form of `new` or `delete`)

These functions are only used as part of a RAII-like struct, so there should not been any memory leaks caused by using them.

I am concerned about the safety of this, specifically with regards to alignment (as an array suitably aligned for `char` might not be properly aligned for `T`).

My questions is this:

*What can I do to make my code perfectly safe? If it already is, why is it?*

**EDIT**:
I am also assuming here that **'T' has a trivial destructor** (well all the types I'm currently using do...)

Also with regards to new_data(std::size_t size)` I am only using it when I am going to manual construct the values (because the corresponding 'type' is to be generated at run time, which will not require allignment)

**EDIT: Telling me to use smart pointers is not an answer** just because using someone else's code could make my code smaller, that does not make it better (primarily due to efficiency and ease of use).

***EDIT: I have decided to use the following modified code:***

```
struct Constant
{
    template<typename T, typename... Targs> static Constant&& construct(Targs... args...)
    {
        return Constant(sizeof(T), new(new char[sizeof(T)]) T(args...));
    }
    template<typename T> static Constant&& construct_default()
    {
        return Constant(sizeof(T), new(new char[sizeof(T)]) T);
    }
    template<typename T, typename... Targs> static Constant&& construct_list(Targs... args...)
    {
        return Constant(sizeof(T), new(new char[sizeof(T)]) T{args...});
    }

    Constant() 
        : Constant(0, nullptr, nullptr) { }
    explicit Constant(std::size_t size, Syntax::Expression* creator = nullptr)
        : Constant(size, new char[size], creator) { allocate(); }
    Constant(const Constant& c)
        : Constant(c.size_value, c.data_pointer, c.creator) { allocate(); }
    Constant(Constant&& c) 
        : Constant(c.size_value, c.data_pointer, c.creator) { c.data_pointer = nullptr; }

private:
    std::size_t size_value = 0;
    char* data_pointer = nullptr;

public:
    Syntax::Expression* creator = nullptr;
    std::size_t size() const { return size_value; }
    template<typename T = char*> T data() { return reinterpret_cast<T>(data_pointer); }
    template<typename T = const char*> T data() const { return reinterpret_cast<T>(data_pointer); }

    template<typename T> Constant&& copy() const
    {
        return Constant(size_value, new (new char[sizeof(T)]) T(*reinterpret_cast<T*>(data_pointer)), creator);
    }
    template<typename T> Constant&& copy(Syntax::Expression* e) const
    {
        return Constant(size_value, new (new char[sizeof(T)]) T(*reinterpret_cast<T*>(data_pointer)), e);
    }

    Constant&& raw_copy() const
    {
        return Constant(size_value, std::memcpy(new char[size_value], data_pointer, size_value), creator);
    }
    Constant&& raw_copy(Syntax::Expression* e) const
    {
        return Constant(size_value, std::memcpy(new char[size_value], data_pointer, size_value), e);
    }

    Constant& operator =(const Constant& c)
    {
        deallocate();
        size_value = c.size_value;
        data_pointer = c.data_pointer;
        creator = c.creator;
        allocate();
        return *this;
    }
    Constant& operator =(Constant&& c)
    {
        deallocate();
        size_value = c.size_value;
        data_pointer = c.data_pointer;
        creator = c.creator;
        c.data_pointer = nullptr;
        return *this;
    }

    ~Constant() { deallocate(); }
private:
    Constant(std::size_t size, void* data, Syntax::Expression* creator = nullptr)
        : size_value(size), data_pointer(reinterpret_cast<char*>(data)), creator(creator) { }

    static std::map<void*, std::size_t> allocation_table;
    void allocate() const
    {
        if (data_pointer == nullptr)
            return;

        if (allocation_table.count(data_pointer) == 0)
            allocation_table[data_pointer] = 1;
        else allocation_table[data_pointer]++;
    }
    void deallocate() const
    {
        if (data_pointer == nullptr)
            return;

        if ((allocation_table[data_pointer] -= 1) == 0)
        {
            delete[] data_pointer;
            allocation_table.erase(data_pointer);
        }
    }
};
std::map<void*, std::size_t> Constant::allocation_table = {};
```

Thank you to everyone who helped me. Though my question was never actually fully answered, based on my reading on http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new, I am pretty sure my code is safe (though not certain). Also I may have the `...` syntax completely wrong, but I should find out when I actually try and compile it (and use it).

Comment: Do you do this out of academic interest? Otherwise, what is your actual goal? You are most likely reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @Baum As I said it's part of a RAII structure I'm using, that is basically a handle to garbage-collected memory (which does not point back to the handles).
So partly academic interest, and partly because I'm too lazy too look for a type that does exactly what I want, also I'm only using the standard library.

Comment: I would just use smart pointers. They are better than anything you can come up with as many people have examined the code over the years and any improvements would have been introduced. They are very easy to use and are well documented.

Answer (score 4):

You're basically reinventing:

```
T* t = new T(value);
T* u = new T(std::move(value));
```

except it's much less functional, because I can't use any other constructor of `T` besides copy and move. Not even default! (Note also that your second constructor is incorrect - you should `forward` from `value`, not copy it, and having a forwarding-reference constructor makes having an lvalue reference constructor redundant. Also you want to create a `decay_t<T>`, not a `T` - because `T` can be a reference type).

And it's much less safe because... well, what do I do with `t` and `u` at the end? You would call `delete_data()`. That frees the memory, but it **doesn't destroy the objects**. You're missing a destructor call. `delete t` does both for you.

Basically, this gives you no advantage and a few important disadvantages over just normal raw `new` and `delete`. And modern C++ has tools that have advantages over those: smart pointers. When in doubt, use those instead.

---

It's also worth pointing out, that these two overloads:

```
static char* new_data(std::size_t size);
template<typename T> static char* new_data(T&& value);
```

do *wildly* different things in a way that could be very confusing. `new_data(42)` allocates 4 bytes and placement-`new`s `42` into there. `new_data((size_t)42)` allocates 42 bytes. That's just very error prone.

Comment: Why should I use 'std::move'/'std::forward'? also what's the problem if 'T' is a reference type?
Also Destruction should be trivial for any types I use so I don't need to worry about it.
The reason I didn't use `new T(value);` is because I wan't to be able to safely destroy the objects even if I don't know the type that was used with 'new' (I could have just used `free(data)` and `malloc(sizeof(T))`)

Comment: @Isaac There isn't anything particularly safe about just going around the language mechanisms like this. You're not gaining anything. If you want to use `malloc` and `free`, just use it where you want to use it - don't hide it somewhere.

Comment: @Isaac Based on your edit, it looks like you're trying to reinvent `shared_ptr`. Also having overloads for `new_data` that do *wildly* different things based on the argument is not a good idea.

Comment: shouldn't it call `static char* new_data(std::size_t size) { return new char[size]; }` ?
Thanks for that, I will look into it (I never really understood smart-pointers, and it seems easier to make my own...)

Comment: thanks for that, the only reason I put the code in functions was so I could ask this question concisely without having to show the code of `struct Constant`, so I'll just expand the functions inline based on what overload I think they should call.
Also regarding `shared_ptr`, the main problem is it is needs to know what type of object it points to, I want to point to arbitrary objects (which possibly no C++ type, so I want to treat them as arrays of bytes).

Comment: @Isaac So `shared_ptr<vector<char>>`?

Comment: how am I supposed to cast a `vector<char>` to a `T`, for some random `T` ???
Also how would that be better? `vector<char>` has more overhead then a `char` array

Answer (score 1):

You could allocate `std::max_align_t` instead of `char`, in order to have safely-aligned objects.

However, this doesn't address the issue that neither constructors, nor destructors, are going to get invoked here.

`RAII` is already a solved issue. There is no reason to reinvent this wheel, in some odd manner. Use containers, and/or `std::shared_ptr`, and your code will be `RAII`-safe, by default.

Comment: IIRC, the C++ standard warranties that `char[size]` allocations will be properly aligned for any `Type` of `sizeof(Type) <= size`, very much like what `malloc()` would do.

Comment: @Sam  thanks, I didn't want to use that as it would waste space if `sizeof(T)` is not a multiple of `sizeof(std::max_align_t)`

Comment: Given that `std::max_align_t` is, typically, 4 or 8 bytes long, I'm sure that those can be spared, amongst the gigabytes in your server.

Comment: @Sam oh your right (it's 8-bytes for me), I was thinking it should be 16/32/64 bytes long (for SSE packed structures, which I believe require alignment)
Also I'm not using a server, but the number & size of objects I am creating is small, so it shouldn't matter too much.